# mac sips program seems to ignore --padColor option

Tags: macos, sips

I have a 128x256 png file I am trying to pad to 512x512 with sips but sips always seems to pad with transparency rather than the specified padColor.  What am I doing wrong?

```
sips junk-128x256.png --padToHeightWidth 512 512 --padColor 00FF00 --out junk-512x512.png
```

The resulting image is 512x512 but with transparent padding.

Answer (score 5):

The sips command will only pad with color for jpg and bmp file formats.  Other file types are always padded with white.  In order to add a colored padding to a png file, first convert to bmp and then pad and convert back to png.

```
sips junk.png -s format bmp --out junk.bmp
sips junk.bmp -s format png --padToHeightWidth 512 512 --padColor 00FF00 --out junk-512x512.png
```